# Specifying the link function and 'normal' family when fitting an GLM model in R

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I have a dataset that are normally distributed and I am trying to fit the data into a GLM model in R. The model that I used for a previous dataset had a binomial distribution and I used the GLM code: model1 <- glm(formula = Y$mat ~ X, family = binomial(link = "probit")). 
How would I specify the 'family' parameter for a 'normal' distribution as there doesn't seem to be a value for this in the documentation, and what is the default link function for a normal distribution?

Answer (score 2):

`family = gaussian` is the default and is also another name for the normal distribution!

Comment: @MattP, if this was useful for you will you please accept the answer? Thank you.